# App bundle with one main executable and one helper app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I wrote an app which uses an external ask pass(a small app I wrote for the gui tool) cmd line tool for accessing ssh. Everything works fine so far in development mode. But when I want to archive/bundle the app it creates me a zip-file with 2 executables.

After googling, I've found out that I have to put the ask pass tool in content/macos . Well.. but how ? I don't know how to do that with XCode4 and google didn't show me a solution, link tip or whatever. Maybe anyone of you knows a tutorial / the solution ?

Regards, Alex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have an app quite like this (a main GUI app and a helper app).

To get the helper app embedded into the main app, go to the "Build Phases" tab of your project and you can add a "Copy Files" build phase.

To get to Build Phases, click on the main project in the File Inspector (it's usually the top-most thing) and then you'll see a window with "Project" and "Targets" in a drop down table on the left side.  Choose the target you want to add your helper app to, and that's where you can add the "Copy Files" build phase.

If you have trouble finding it, let me know and I can attempt to prepare a screenshot (can't do it just yet cause my own project is under NDA).

Comment: Two additions: In the copy build phase it's good practice to place the helper binary in your "Plugins" bundle folder, and make sure you set "Skip Install" to "Yes" under build settings, or you'll have trouble archiving it later.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same. Should I setup a dependency? (i.e., always build helper app before building main app). Can I debug the helper app code when I run the main app in Xcode? Do I have to match configurations somewhere? (i.e., release-release, debug-debug)