# Archive of my application doesn’t contain the helper app

Tags: xcode, cocoa, xcode5

My main application contains a helper app. Both are sanboxed. When I build the release target of the application, all works fine and the helper is in the bundle of the main application in Contents/Library/LoginItems.
 
In the helper app's target build settings tab, I’ve set the 'Skip Install’ option to YES.

The `‘per-configuration Build Products Path’` of the Built Locations and The ‘Installation Directory’ in Deployment are set to :

`build/Release/Main.app/Contents/library/Loginitems`

When I archive the application, the helper is missing. So, what should I do ?

Comment: You need to use a rule in *Build Phases*.  See the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138181/app-bundle-with-one-main-executable-and-one-helper-app

Comment: Yes, I've read this post but that wasn't really clear for me because the explanations concerned Xcode 4. I've added a built rule with Destination > Wrapper and Subpath > 'Contents/Library/LoginItems' and all works fine now. Thank you very much. Do you know how I can built the release product with root permissions ?